# Migration from Hyper-V to ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd, vmware-vmdk

I am in the process of migrating my machines from Hyper-V to ESXi and I was just wondering what is the best way to do so?

I tried just copying the hyper-v disk file, creating a new vmware workstation machine that uses that VHD and it just worked (I guess they support VHD files). Can ESXi do the same? Can I just install ESXi, create a new machine that uses the VHD file and it should boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd take a look at [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/). It can import a Hyper-V machine the same way it imports physical servers. I'm not sure there's a way to import directly from the vhd.

I've used Converter quite a bit, and it's pretty simple/quick process.

Comment: so, it connects to the hyper-v server and dumps a vmware compatible image?

Comment: Yes, it will actually connect directly to the ESXi server and when completed, you'll have a ready-to-boot VM within ESXi.

Comment: @acanthus - Not exactly. It'll connect to your guest virtual machines. It doesn't know anything about Hyper-V specifically. It'll install a service on the Hyper-V Guest, then copy its data out to your vSphere environment.